# Echo tags used to describe the theme

Tags: functions, themes, tags, child-theme

I've got a plugin I am working on to return an instance of the WP_Theme object properties. The plugin essentially allows for a simple child-theme creation.

```
/*
Theme Name:     <?php echo $new_theme_title, '\n'; ?>
Description:    <?php echo $new_theme_description, '\n'; ?>
Author:         <?php echo $new_theme_author, '\n'; ?>
Template:       <?php echo $parent_theme_template, '\n'; ?>
Author URI:     <?php echo 'http://buildtheweb.design', '\n'; ?>
Version:        <?php $my_theme = wp_get_theme();echo $my_theme->get( 'Name' ) . " is version " . $my_theme->get( 'Version' ), '\n';?>
License:        See <?php echo $parent_theme_template . '(Google Search)', '\n'; ?>
License URI:    See <?php echo $parent_theme_template . '(Google Search)', '\n'; ?>
Tags:           <?php $my_theme = wp_get_theme(); echo $my_theme->get( 'Tags' ); ?>
Text Domain:    <?php echo $parent_theme_template. '-child' , '\n'; ?>
*/
```

Creates and returns everything we want except the tags. I don't know how to get the array to show the parent theme tags.

```
/*
Theme Name:     New Child Theme
Description:    Testing our awesome child theme creation plugin
Author:         Jarod Thornton
Template:       twentysixteen
Author URI:     http://buildtheweb.design
Version:        Twenty Sixteen is version 1.1
License:        http://domain.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css
License URI:    ^
Tags:           Array
Text Domain:    twentysixteen-child
*/
```

I appreciate any insight.

Comment: `echo implode(", ", $my_theme->get( 'Tags' ));` ?

Comment: Ah, TY. If you post this as an informed answer I will accept. Otherwise Bruno Cantuaria will get it. JS

Comment: Wait!. haha. I am just kidding. Let Bruno score some points ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's outputting the word `Array` which is self explanatory. Instead of direct echoing it, you will need to turn the array into a string. Try `implode`, something like:

```
Tags:           <?php $my_theme = wp_get_theme(); echo implode(', ', $my_theme->get( 'Tags' ) ); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use `echo implode(", ", $my_theme->get( 'Tags' ));`, but your answer got me there.